# iOS UI Containers

Tags: ios, user-interface, containers

I've tried to study the visual objects in XCode but I dont understand which of them fits my need. What I need is something that corresponds to what in html is a `DIV` or any other `html-element` that can be used as a "container". Here is the description of my problem:

I need to display 3 container/areas in my app.
In each container I will put an unknown number of buttons. Its about dynamically created buttons.

In html I would have 3 `DIVs`. And then add/remove buttons from this divs when needed.

How can you do the same thing in Objective-C? I have read about `drawRect` or stuff like that. But is that the only/best way to do it? Isn't there an IU object that can be used for this?

Comment: Have a look at `UIView`

Comment: Normally, in iOS you should dispose each subview by setting it's frame. There are some exceptions: UITableView, UICollectionView and [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).
If you decide to dispose your subviews programmatically, it will be very convinient to do this in `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of UIViewController or in UIView's `-layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the "container" would be the UIView.  You can attach views to other views with:

```
[view1 addSubview: view2];
```

view2's frame will determine where it is located within view1.  Since buttons and other objects are  UIViews, as well, they are added as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

It's a UIVIew but you shouldn't use it the same way you use a DIV.

It's absolutely essential that you understand the iOS interface paradigm. Please, do yourself a favor and read the HIG: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html